# Can This Integral Be Solved Using Either A Stochastic Approach or As Structured Assuming Lognormality?

Tags: exponential-function, indefinite-integrals, brownian-motion

I am interested in identifying the expected value of a negative exponential function:

$1-e^{-pw(x-r)}$

where x is a lognormal variable so that the expected value of the function is:

$\int{[1-e^{-pw(x-r)}]\frac{-e^{-\frac{1}{2}\frac{(log(x)-\mu)^2}{\sigma^2}}}{x \sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}dx}$

Since x is effectively a Brownian motion with known terminal T (so the only issue is uncertainty), can I structure the integral differently to get the expected value of the function?

I've tried looking at the problem in the following way, assuming that x follows a Brownian motion:

$\int{[1-e^{-pw((\mu-r)t + \sigma x)}]\frac{-e^{-\frac{1}{2}\frac{x^2}{t}}}{\sqrt{t}\sqrt{2\pi}}dx}$

but am not sure that this is the right way to think about solving the problem.

I used a Taylor series approximation to solve the first integral, but it's a poor approximation for the range of values I am considering for p and t (embedded in $\mu$ and $\sigma$ in the first formulation).

Answer (score 0):

There are all sorts
of extraneous variables there,
so I'll write

$\begin{array}\\
\int{[1-e^{-pw((\mu-r)t + \sigma x)}]\frac{-e^{-\frac{1}{2}\frac{x^2}{t}}}{\sqrt{t}\sqrt{2\pi}}dx}
&=\int{[1-e^{-at + s x)}]\frac{-e^{-\frac{x^2}{2t}}}{\sqrt{2\pi t}}dx}\\
&=\int\frac{-e^{-\frac{x^2}{2t}}}{\sqrt{2\pi t}}dx
-\int{e^{-at + s x}\frac{-e^{-\frac{x^2}{2t}}}{\sqrt{2\pi t}}dx}\\
&=-\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi t}}\int e^{-\frac{x^2}{2t}}dx
+\frac{e^{-at}}{\sqrt{2\pi t}}\int e^{-\frac{x^2}{2t}+sx}dx\\
\end{array}
$

These are both
versions of the
normal distribution,
with the second having
its peak shifted away from zero.

You should be able to take it from here.